# How do I make this tile-based GUI with GroupLayout (or any other layout!)

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, grouplayout, gaps-in-visuals

I am trying to achieve the following sort of tile-based setup : [image: Game Board]

This is what my code is currently producing : [image: Clearly not the right game board.]

Below is my current code snippet that is generating this.  For clarification, I have tried to combine the `northCentralArea` and `southCentralArea` components (Quest 3, Quest 4... etc. to THE GRINNING LION TAVERN; and CASTLE WATERDEEP, Advanced Choice 3... etc. to Intrigue Discard) into single `JPanel` components of their own in hopes that it would be easier to align within the `GroupLayout` setup.  The "player area" at the bottom is also in its own `JPanel`.

```
private void generateLayout() {
        GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);

        layout.setAutoCreateGaps(true);
        layout.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);

        layout.setHorizontalGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                 .addGap(100)
                 .addComponent(advancedBuildingTiles[20])
                 .addComponent(advancedBuildingTiles[12])
                 .addComponent(advancedBuildingTiles[6])
                 .addComponent(advancedBuildingTiles[14])
                 .addComponent(advancedBuildingTiles[23])
                 .addGap(100))
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                 .addGap(50)
                 .addComponent(advancedBuildingTiles[16])
                 .addComponent(advancedBuildingTiles[8])
                 .addComponent(advancedBuildingTiles[2])
                 .addComponent(advancedBuildingTiles[0])
                 .addComponent(advancedBuildingTiles[4])
                 .addComponent(advancedBuildingTiles[11])
                 .addComponent(advancedBuildingTiles[19])
                 .addGap(50))
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.CENTER)
                 .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                      .addComponent(availableQuests[0])
                      .addComponent(availableQuests[1]))
                 .addComponent(northCentralArea)
                 .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                      .addComponent(basicBuildingTiles[6])
                      .addComponent(advancedBuildingChoices[1])
                      .addComponent(advancedBuildingChoices[2])
                      .addComponent(basicBuildingTiles[7]))
                 .addComponent(southCentralArea)
                 .addComponent(playerArea))                 
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                 .addGap(50)
                 .addComponent(advancedBuildingTiles[18])
                 .addComponent(advancedBuildingTiles[10])
                 .addComponent(advancedBuildingTiles[5])
                 .addComponent(advancedBuildingTiles[1])
                 .addComponent(advancedBuildingTiles[3])
                 .addComponent(advancedBuildingTiles[9])
                 .addComponent(advancedBuildingTiles[17])
                 .addGap(50))
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                 .addGap(100)
                 .addComponent(advancedBuildingTiles[22])
                 .addComponent(advancedBuildingTiles[15])
                 .addComponent(advancedBuildingTiles[7])
                 .addComponent(advancedBuildingTiles[13])
                 .addComponent(advancedBuildingTiles[21])
                 .addGap(100)));

        layout.setVerticalGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                 .addGap(200)
                 .addComponent(availableQuests[0])
                 .addComponent(availableQuests[1]))
                 .addGap(200)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                 .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                      .addGap(50)
                      .addComponent(advancedBuildingTiles[16])
                      .addComponent(northCentralArea)
                      .addComponent(advancedBuildingTiles[18])
                      .addGap(50))  
                 .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                      .addComponent(advancedBuildingTiles[20])
                      .addComponent(advancedBuildingTiles[8])
                      .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                      .addComponent(advancedBuildingTiles[10])
                      .addComponent(advancedBuildingTiles[22]))
                 .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                      .addComponent(advancedBuildingTiles[12])
                      .addComponent(advancedBuildingTiles[2])
                      .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                      .addComponent(advancedBuildingTiles[5])
                      .addComponent(advancedBuildingTiles[15]))
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                 .addComponent(advancedBuildingTiles[6])
                 .addComponent(advancedBuildingTiles[0])
                 .addComponent(basicBuildingTiles[6])
                 .addComponent(advancedBuildingChoices[1])
                 .addComponent(advancedBuildingChoices[2])
                 .addComponent(basicBuildingTiles[7])
                 .addComponent(advancedBuildingTiles[1])
                 .addComponent(advancedBuildingTiles[7]))
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                 .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                      .addComponent(advancedBuildingTiles[14])
                      .addComponent(advancedBuildingTiles[4])
                      .addComponent(southCentralArea)
                      .addComponent(advancedBuildingTiles[3])
                      .addComponent(advancedBuildingTiles[13])) 
                 .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                      .addComponent(advancedBuildingTiles[23])
                      .addComponent(advancedBuildingTiles[11])
                      .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                      .addComponent(advancedBuildingTiles[9])
                      .addComponent(advancedBuildingTiles[21]))
                 .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                      .addGap(50)
                      .addComponent(advancedBuildingTiles[19])
                      .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                      .addComponent(advancedBuildingTiles[17])
                      .addGap(50))
            .addGap(200)
            .addComponent(playerArea)
            .addGap(200))));
    }
```

Clearly I am not understanding what it takes to make this work.  Any help would be much appreciated.  Even if it means switching to a different layout manager (I was hoping to use this as a good opportunity to learn GroupLayout). Cheers!

Comment: Just advice break that to more parts.Slice That image into multiple parts and you can even use more layouts like that and When you decide to make more*components* included to your map.It will be way way way easyer

Comment: You could use a combination of BorderLayout, GridLayout and GridBagLayout

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks to both for your idea of changing my direction.  I will probably answer my own question with this type of advice.